# JavaScript number spinner, working with jQuery 2.x

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I want to use some variant of "number" spinner,  that will work with jQuery 2.x.

jQuery UI Spinner - http://jqueryui.com/spinner/ - doesn't work with newest jQuery, and I need jQuery 2 in the project for something else. (I don't think I can "mix" two jQuery versions on one webpage.)

Examples on jsfiddle:

jQuery UI spinner with jQuery 1.9 - working perfectly

http://jsfiddle.net/9qyGQ/1/

jQuery UI spinner with jQuery 2.x - not working at all

http://jsfiddle.net/9qyGQ/2/

The code is the same at both, only difference is a new jQuery loaded at the second one

HTML:

```
<p>
    <label for="spinner">Select a value:</label>
    <input id="spinner" name="value">
</p>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
    var spinner = $("#spinner").spinner();
});
```

edit:

Just to be clear, by "number spinner", I don't mean a spinning icon, but something like this

[image: Example of a number spinner]

Comment: You can use both jQuery releases. Search for jquery noConflict.

Comment: Hm. Is that the "correct" way to do it - load two jQuery versions just because of a spinner?

Comment: (if I decypher their bug tracking system, I will leave a jQuery UI bugreport, but that's not really a help for me now)

Comment: Did you try `<input type="number">`?

Comment: @hjpotter92: that works only in WebKit browsers, apparently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you include jQuery core js after jQuery UI. Reverse the order and it should be fine

```
jquery-1.10.2.min.js should be include before jquery-ui.js
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9qyGQ/3/)**

Comment: Ah, should've opened the fiddle link :P

Comment: Oh. In that case, I am not sure why it doesn't work in my own application, but I guess it's something completely unrelated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

its just ordering of js files.. above answer by Felix is correct and working fine..